# Curve fitting with an integral function involved

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, numerical-integration, non-linear-regression

I have a 2 parameter model that includes an integral function and I´m quite lost how to solve this.

My data consists of a set of given molecule sizes, *r_m*, and a calculated response, *K*.

The theoretical model is a function of this molecule size, *r_m*, but also involves the integral of the Gaussian distribution (to make it simpler) of the pore size distribution of an adsorbent material. So it has the following form:

[image: Theoretical Model Equations]

*r_p* and *s_p* are the 2 parameters.

So far I've tried to solve this in MATLAB based on the following post:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/nonlinear-data-fitting.html

and this is my code so far:

```
Data = ...
[0.5    1
 1.1    0.83
 1.6    0.74
 2.2    0.55
 2.5    0.28
 3.5    0];


r = Data(:,1);
K_exp = Data(:,2);

F = @(x,xdata) quad( (exp(-1/2.*((xdata - x(1))/x(2)).^2).*(1 - (xdata(1)/xdata).^2)),xdata(1),120)./quad(exp(-1/2.*((xdata - x(1))/x(2)).^2,0,120) ; ;

x0 = [6 0.5] ;

[x,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(F,x0,r,K_exp)
```

Does this adaption make sense? I'm not sure on the one hand how to properly include an integral into the fitting syntax, and on the other hand I don´t know how to properly tell MATLAB that the lower bound of integration for the numerator should be the size of the molecule, *r_m*. What I'm imaging is that *xdata* is some sort of vector for the size, *r*, as in the example in the link for time, *t*. However, the lower limit of integration is not fixed but varies for each of the points I want to fit.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You do not need the integral in the denominator as you can calculate that integral by hand. That will at least save you some trouble/time.

Comment: wouldn´t I still need to include it since the integral includes the parameters to be fitted? I think another option I have for that is to include a normalization constant in the numerator and get rid of the denominator by making it = 1, but I figured if I can deal with the numerator the denominator shouldn´t be a problem.

Comment: Absolutely, the exact integral would still depend on the parameters. So it wont solve your problems, but it will at least be faster as you would only have to integrate 1 function rather than two.